# Trouble with callback function in asynchronous 'Post'

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, and I am having an issue with a line of code executing before the previous line has finished. From what I understand, I need to create a callback function which will make the last line wait for the previous line to finish. My program takes user input and uses an asynchronous 'post' to send it to a website, and then a message is returned. My original problem occurred when I had the two following lines of code together:

```
    req.send(JSON.stringify(payload))
    event.preventDefault();
```

preventDefault() is not waiting for the send() function to finish. I have tried implementing a callback function, but I am having problems with that as well.

```
    function sendReq(callback){
        req.send(JSON.stringify(payload), function(){
            callback();
        });
    }
    sendReq(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Here is my entire code in case that helps.

```
    var apiKey = "appid=fa7d80c48643dfadde2cced1b1be6ca1";
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bindButtons);
    function bindButtons(){
        document.getElementById('dataSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(event){
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var payload = {longUrl:null};
            payload.longUrl = document.getElementById('inputData').value;
            req.open('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post&' + apiKey, true);
            req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            req.addEventListener('load',function(){
                if(req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400){
                    document.getElementById('outputData').textContent = response.longUrl;
                } 
                else 
                    console.log("Error in network request");
            });
            function sendReq(callback){
                req.send(JSON.stringify(payload), function(){
                    callback();
                });
            }
            sendReq(function(){
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` has to be called synchronously because the default handler will be called synchronously.  If you are trying to override the default handler, then you will always call it.  What is the purpose of delaying it until the request is finished?

Comment: The error I am receiving is: `VM53:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: I am not receiving the response message. I was told by an instructor that it is because `event.preventDefault();` is being executed before the send() function finishes execution

Comment: You're asking an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/476). Please start again with the actual problem you have and the actual thing you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to send user input to a website using the 'Post' method and with the true flag set making it asynchronous. It needs to send a content-type of application/json. The website then returns data which needs to be displayed.

Comment: And how does `event.preventDefault()` factor into this...?

Comment: @deceze is correct and your instructor is not.  You need to ask about the problem you are having, not about the solution your instructor incorrectly said might solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand how callbacks work. Check out this article from recurial.com: [Understanding callback functions in Javascript](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/)

You can't "wait" in JavaScript[*] - due to something called ["Run-to-completion" semantics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop): your code always runs in response to an *event* (such as "DOMContentLoaded", "click", or XHR's "load") and no more events - and no other event handlers - will be processed until your currently running code finishes (typically by `return`-ing from the outermost function -- the event handler).

Long-running JS code makes the web page freeze, which is why you were asked to write an asynchronous request in the first place -- synchronous XHR will cause the page to freeze while your code waits for the response from the server.

To avoid the freezes and still get the job done, you can structure your code as a series of callbacks: after you start an asynchronous request you return from the current function and let the system call you back when it has the response. The only moment when you can use the response is in the callback, by the very definition of the callback.

In your case, the callback that indicates that the response is available is the `load` handler. That's where you should move your `var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);` line.

---

PS. `preventDefault()` is completely unrelated to your situation, it can't be used to "wait for the send() function to finish"; it's used in cases when you handle an event (such as `onsubmit` for a `<form>`) and you want to prevent something that the browser does by default when this event fires (in the `<form>` example -- well -- submitting the form).

PPS. After you figure out the basics and start writing code that has more than 2 callbacks in a row, look up "promises".

PPPS. [*] *Ignore this remark, I added it just to be precise, as it will only confuse you at this stage:* You can't "wait" in JavaScript unless you're writing a ["generator"](http://www.2ality.com/2015/03/no-promises.html) and/or using the currently unavailable [async/await](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/)).